# Can you install FFmpeg using only command promt?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was really just wondering if you could install FFmpeg using just command promt specifically. Also just adding windows paths using it as well.

I tried adding it myself but it wouldn't run properly.

[image: FFmpeg Windows Command Line - Screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if you could install FFmpeg using just the command prompt.

FFmpeg (`ffmpeg`, `ffplay` and `ffprobe`) are each stand-alone command line utilities. There is nothing to install. You simply run them directly e.g.:

```
ffmpeg option1 option2 [...]
ffplay option1 option2 [...]
ffprobe option1 option2 [...]
```

> How do l add Windows Paths using the command line as well?

To permanently add a Path, you would want to use the Windows [setx](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command, as displayed in your screenshot, probably with the `/M` option so any Path to FFmpeg is added to the System (rather than User) variables.

> I tried adding it myself but it wouldn't run properly.

Unfortunately, this doesn't really provide  much information regarding the problem(s) you're facing.

However, be aware that restarting `explorer.exe` (Windows Explorer) may be necessary for newly added Paths to work correctly (you may be able to simply restart the Windows Explorer process manually via Task Manager or do the old "Reboot the PC" trick). Also be aware that using `setx` with `/M` will typically require admin privileges.